# Unable to get the same view when included programmatically instead of xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

Recently I face one problem in including layout programmatically.

**Scenario:**

1. I have main layout and one sub layout.
2. I want to include sub layout to main layout programmatically.
3. Main layout root is relative layout and sub layout root is `framelayout`.
4. I want to add sub layout to be added bottom in the main layout for that I have added property to the sub layout.
5. strangely if I added sub layout to the main layout statically(in xml using include tag) then it work as expected(stick to bottom) but not work when added programmatically.

mainlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ly_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AppintroActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

sublayout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_bottom_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/dull_black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_skip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:text="Skip"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/forward" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dots"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

This is how I include using java

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View bottomlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.frame));//bottom is mysublayout.xml

ly_root.addView(bottomlayout);//ly_root is my mainlayout.xml's root element's id
```

[image: This is a screenshot when include layout programmatically,But it is incorrect as sublayout should be in bottom instead of top]

[image: This is a screenshot when using xml including tag]

So Please give me suggestion that how can I achieve exactly same result as including using xml, by using java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use  "*LayoutParams*" to add a view to a layout. like this:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    par.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    ly_root.addView(bottomlayout,par);
```

Comment: Done bro,Thank you for helping me @mehd

Answer (score 1):

```
RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);

View frame = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sub_layout,null); 

lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 

LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); // You might want to tweak these to WRAP_CONTENT

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

layout.addView(frame, lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the `RelativeLayout` rules in the params and add it along with the params, you can do something like below:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

ly_root.addView(bottomlayout, params);
```

Please let me know if you have trouble implementing.